# MonoTouch - UITapGesture not working on child controls

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am creating a grid like control for an iPad application. Basically it consists of a collection of `UIView`'s added to a parent `UIView` in a grid like fashion - with each `UIView` representing some data from my data source. This works fine.

I implement a `UITapGesture` for each `UIView` that represents a cell. Basically a tap on the cell will change the data in my data source. The tap doesn't seem to fire though.

If i add a tap gesture to the parent `UIView` which encapsulates these individual views then it is recognized. I have set the property `UserInteractionEnabled` to `true` on all `UIView`s as well as `ExclusiveTouch` property on the parent view to `false`. But no luck.

Not sure if this is an apple controls issue (doubt it) or something i am missing (highly probable).

Comment: Are you using UITapGestureRecognizer? That should be the easiest.

Comment: would need to see the code, as there should be no issue in doing what you are wanting. Must be something in the way of cell views that is blocking recognizer.

Comment: Hi Guys Thanks a lot for your feedback. I realized it was something i had done which caused the child UIView to not receive the event. My bad as i had thought.